# Not able to get data using MessengerExtensions.requestPaymentCredentials

Tags: facebook, sdk, facebook-messenger, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

Has anyone tried MessengerExtensions.requestPaymentCredentials using the facebook messenger extension sdk ([refer documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-extension)) ?
I am trying to call this in my client side javascript code and I am not getting any data. Below code doesn't alert me neither with email nor with error.

Here is my client side javascript code :

```
window.extAsyncInit = function() {
   MessengerExtensions.requestPaymentCredentials(function success(name, email, cardType, cardLastFourDigits, shippingAddress) {
    alert("Email" +email);
    }, function error(err) {
      alert("Messenger Extension error in getting payment credentials" + err);
    });
};
```

Note : I am able to get user profile data using MessengerExtensions.getUserID by similar code.

Comment: Such a facebook err :)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I  am having a similar issue.